# Vertical alignment in minipages

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \centering
    \uline{\bfseries Gewindearten}\\
    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        {\scriptsize
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.77\linewidth}     
                \centering
                \setlength\extrarowheight{0.15cm}
                \begin{tabular}{@{} l|l|l @{}}
                    Bezeichung & Durchmesser & Fläche\\\hline
                    Außen-/Nenn- & $d$ & $A_{\!N\Bstrut} = \frac{\pi d^2}{4}$\\
                    \textcolor{blue}{Flanken-} & $d_{2\Bstrut} = d-0,64952 \cdot P$ & $A_2 = \frac{\pi d_2^2}{4}$\\
                    \textcolor{green}{Kern-} & $d_{3\Bstrut} = d-1,22687 \cdot P$ & $A_3 = \frac{\pi d_3^2}{4}$\\
                    \textcolor{red}{Spannungs-} & $d_{S\Bstrut} = 0,5 \cdot (d_2 + d_3) \cdot P$ & $A_S = \frac{\pi d_3^2}{4}$\\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{minipage}\hfill     
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\linewidth} 
                \centering  
                $P$\\
                =\\ 
                Gewindesteigung\\
        \end{minipage}}\hfill
        \vspace*{0.2cm}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \centering  
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}}
            \hfill
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \hfill
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \centering
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}}
            \hfill
        \end{minipage}\hfill
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{0.2cm}
        {\tiny
            \begin{tabular}{@{} L{1.3cm}C{1.1cm}L{5.96cm} @{}}
                Gewindetyp & Ausführung & Beschreibung\\\hline
                Spitzgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}& Übliches Befestigunsgewinde\\
                Trapezgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Bewegungsgewinde (Bsp.: Leitspindeln)\\
                Rundgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Bewegungsgewinde für hochverschmutzte Geräte\\
                Sägegewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Bewegungsgewinde bei einseitiger Belastungsrichtung\\
                Flachgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Nicht abgeschrägtes Ineinandergreifen der Zähne\\
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
\end{document}
```

Producing this page:
[image]

How can I fix the vertical alignment of each of the pages? I already tried `\vfill` as well as `\raisebox`, though uncessfully. The issue is present in the minipage right to the small table, the pictures below the table as well as the table on the right most minipage.

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't "accept" the first good answer that comes your way right away, unless you really really wish to discourage other would-be answer writers from providing additional solutions. You are, of course, encouraged to up-vote any good answers immediately. However, site guidelines suggest that one should wait several hours, and maybe even a day or so, before "accepting" the answer that's most helpful.

Comment: @Mico I just don't expect anybody to answer a question that has already been sufficiently answered.. so I want to give the person that answered it the deserved reputation. I will consider what you said for the future though.

Comment: There's usually more than one good way to typeset tabular material. An answer that may appear to you to be "sufficiently good" at first glance may turn out to be inferior to another answer that somebody else might come up with. However, you won't find out about these other solution possibilities if you, de facto, discourage people from posting them in the first place.

Comment: @Mico I do understand you point and will, as said, take this into consideration for future activities on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure quite what layout you want, but this is perhaps closer:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.8cm, left = 1cm, right = 1cm, bottom = 0.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \centering
    \uline{\bfseries Gewindearten}

    \vspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        {\scriptsize
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}     
                \centering
        \vspace{0cm}
                \setlength\extrarowheight{0.15cm}
                \begin{tabular}{@{} l|l|l @{}}
                    Bezeichung & Durchmesser & Fläche\\\hline
                    Außen-/Nenn- & $d$ & $A_{\!N\Bstrut} = \frac{\pi d^2}{4}$\\
                    \textcolor{blue}{Flanken-} & $d_{2\Bstrut} = d-0,64952 \cdot P$ & $A_2 = \frac{\pi d_2^2}{4}$\\
                    \textcolor{green}{Kern-} & $d_{3\Bstrut} = d-1,22687 \cdot P$ & $A_3 = \frac{\pi d_3^2}{4}$\\
                    \textcolor{red}{Spannungs-} & $d_{S\Bstrut} = 0,5 \cdot (d_2 + d_3) \cdot P$ & $A_S = \frac{\pi d_3^2}{4}$\\
                \end{tabular}
            \end{minipage}\hfill     
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.23\linewidth} 
                \centering  
        \vspace{1cm}
                $P$\\
                =\\ 
                Gewindesteigung\\
        \end{minipage}}

        \vspace*{.2cm}

            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}}%
            \hfill
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}}
            \hfill
            \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[height=2.2cm]{example-image-a}}
            \hfill
    \end{minipage}\hfill\vrule\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
        \centering
        \vspace{0cm}
        {\tiny
            \begin{tabular}{@{} L{1.3cm}C{1.1cm}L{5.96cm} @{}}
                Gewindetyp & Ausführung & Beschreibung\\\hline
                Spitzgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}& Übliches Befestigunsgewinde\\
                Trapezgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Bewegungsgewinde (Bsp.: Leitspindeln)\\
                Rundgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Bewegungsgewinde für hochverschmutzte Geräte\\
                Sägegewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Bewegungsgewinde bei einseitiger Belastungsrichtung\\
                Flachgewinde & \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} & Nicht abgeschrägtes Ineinandergreifen der Zähne\\
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've no idea why the vspaces fixed it the way they did, but thank you it worked! Is the a way to vertically center the right table on it's minipage automaticall?

Comment: @Skydiver vertical centre is the default for both minipage and tabular but you have over-ridden that and forced `[t]` top alignment everywhere. i didn't change that.

Comment: Removing the [t] moves the table up instead of down though..

Comment: @Skydiver yes, that would be expected.  If you have `zzzz \begin{tabular}[t]`  then the top row of the table aligns with `zzzz` if you remove the `[t]` or equivalently use `[c]` then the centre of the table aligns with `zzz` so the table is effectively shifted up by half its height.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that doesn't impose `\tiny` on the material on the right-hand half of the page. This should make it a lot easier on your readers to actually *read* and absorb what you've written.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=0.8cm,hmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,array,xcolor,multirow}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{0pt}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\centering
\textbf{Gewindearten}

\vspace{3mm}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth}  % left-hand half
\scriptsize
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}     
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l|>{$}l<{$}|>{$}l<{$} c @{}}
     Bezeichnung & $Durchmesser$ & $Fläche$\\
     \cline{1-3}
     Außen-/Nenn- & 
          d & 
          A_N = \frac{\pi}{4\Bstrut} d^2\\
     \textcolor{blue}{Flanken-} & 
          d_{2} = d-0{,}64952  P & 
          A_2 = \frac{\pi}{4\Bstrut} d_2^2 &
          \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}   
               $P={}$\\Gewindesteigung
              \end{tabular}}\\
     \textcolor{green}{Kern-} & 
          d_{3} = d-1{,}22687  P & 
          A_3 = \frac{\pi}{4\Bstrut} d_3^2\\
     \textcolor{red}{Spannungs-} & 
          d_{S} = 0{,}5  (d_2 + d_3)  P & 
          A_S = \frac{\pi}{4} d_3^2\\
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}

\vspace{4mm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}%   %% end of left-hand half
\hfill\vrule\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\linewidth} % right-hand half
\centering
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{@{} l C{1.6cm}Y @{}}
     Gewindetyp & Ausführung & Beschreibung\\
     \hline
     Spitzgewinde & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
        & Übliches Befestigungsgewinde\\[-1mm]
     Trapezgewinde & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} 
        & Bewegungsgewinde (Bsp.: Leitspindeln)\\[-1mm]
     Rundgewinde & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} 
        & Bewegungsgewinde für hochverschmutzte Geräte\\[-1mm]
     Sägegewinde & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} 
        & Bewegungsgewinde bei einseitiger Belastungsrichtung\\[-1mm]
     Flachgewinde & \includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a} 
        & Nicht abgeschrägtes Ineinandergreifen der Zähne
\end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```